# Выход из цикла по нажатию button

Tags: python, button, tkinter

Код:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title('Test')
window.geometry('500x500')
window.resizable(0, 0)

def playclick():
    label['text'] = 'Работаем..'

def stopclick():
    label['text'] = 'Остановлено'

button1 = Button(window, text="Старт", width=8, height=2, bg="white", fg="green", font="arial 14", command=playclick)
button1.place(x=5, y=5)

button2 = Button(window, text="Стоп", width=8, height=2, bg="white", fg="green", font="arial 14", command=stopclick)
button2.place(x=120, y=5)

label = Label(window, text='Остановлено')
label.place(x=5, y=473)

text = Text(window, height=24,width=69, font="arial 10",wrap=WORD)
text.place(x=5, y=80)
data = "temp" #здесь мы будем выводить лог
text.insert(1.0,data)

# Добавляем скролл
scrollbar = Scrollbar(window)
scrollbar.pack(side='right')
scrollbar['command'] = text.yview() # первая привязка
text['yscrollcommand'] = scrollbar.set # вторая привязка

window.mainloop()
```

Принцип работы: нажимаем кнопку Старт, запускается цикл, в котором меняется текст в data и этот текст выводится в поле text. Цикл длиться до тех пор, пока не будет нажата кнопка Stop. Как это организовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from tkinter import Button, Tk, Label
import random
from threading import Thread

def run():
    Obj['run'] = not Obj['run']
    while Obj['run']:
        tLabel['text'] = random.randrange(10**5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    tLabel = Label(root)
    tLabel.pack()
    Obj = dict(run=False)
    Button(root, text='start/stop', command=lambda: Thread(target=run).start()).pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Благодарю. Все работает.